# SparkPost 400 Bad request Domain Setup?

Tags: laravel, sparkpost

I'm encountering this error after hooking up SparkPost and Laravel. I only want to deploy this application locally for development purposes (localhost). And I don't have any domain at the moment. Does this error have to do with domain setup? Thanks and guide me please.

The error I'm seeing is this:

> Client error: `POST https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "errors": [ { "message":
>   "Invalid domain", "description": "Unconfigured Sending Domain
>    ", "code": "7001" (truncated...)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the image to find how to add a sending domain. After adding, please verify it. 
As you said you only want to send email for development, you can use a simple smtp or even the native php `mail` driver provided by laravel. With Parkpost API, you definitely need a working domain name.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use built in Laravel Mail facade. I want to use package that offers that capability. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use built in Laravel mail facade then you can use beautymail package.

Here is the link for all supported email packages  - http://packalyst.com/packages/tag/email

Go for the maximum downloaded package [ex - beautymail package](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/snowfire/beautymail)